# Laravel from 5.4.* to 5.5* Update error and php version error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've created a laravel project with version  5.4.* and I want the project version to be 5.5.*

I've edited the composer.json but I get this error.
error code: 
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

### - laravel/framework v5.5.9 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.

composer.json code

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
```

}

Comment: You need to upgrade PHP. There is nothing wrong with your Laravel framework. If you are on Ubuntu, install PHP 7 and if you are on Windows and using xampp, download and install new XAMPP after taking backup of `htdocs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your PHP version to 7.0 or higher. You can check the requirements here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a **development environment** try **install**ing the **new version of php**. By installing the new version of xampp you will get the updated version of php.
 Or if you are in production mode upgrade your php version by going to **Select PHP Version** and update it.